# Is it possible to use get_headers after hiding referrer?

Tags: php, href, referrer, get-headers

I'm using this code to get HTTP response:

```
$url = "http://example.com/";
$headers = get_headers($url);
$header = substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
echo = $header;
```

which works great but I need to hide referrer so I am using http://href.li/ like so:

```
$url = "http://href.li/?http://example.com/";
$headers = get_headers($url);
$header = substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
echo = $header;
```

which results in a `200 OK` HTTP status code no matter what the status of the final page is. Is it possible at all to get header from the final page? Or is there another approach to accomplish this while still using a referrer hiding service?

Comment: The `href.li` site doesn't send a redirect. It sends a web page that contains a `<meta  http-equiv="Refresh">` tag and Javascript that calls `window.location.replace()`. I don't think it even tries to connect to the target site, so it can't report on success or failure.

Comment: Can you hide the referer by using curl?

Comment: edited the title, not familiar with curl

Comment: Look it up in the PHP manual, it's the usual way to perform HTTP operations when you want detailed control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a third-party service to hide your referer in this kind of request, you can set it to whatever you need, however, you cannot do it with the `get_headers` function. You could do it with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/stream_context_create). In your case, I imagine it would be something like this:

```
$URL = 'http://example.com/';
$Context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'HEAD',
        'header' => 'Referer: '
    )
));
file_get_contents($URL, false, $Context);
$ResponseHeaders = $http_response_header;

$header = substr($ResponseHeaders[0], 9, 3);
echo $header;
```

`stream_context_create` creates a stream context with whatever options for the request that you specify and `file_get_contents` does the request using that context. Afterwards the script checks [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) which is a kind of a magic variable that is populated after HTTP requests to HTTP URLs and it is available only in the local scope, i.e., right after you call the function making the HTTP request but not, say, in another function that gets executed afterwards. The content of `$http_response_header` is basically the same as the result of `get_header()` function.

(You can also use `GET` in the above example but if you don't need the response body, `HEAD` just gets the headers without the body. By the way, PHPs `get_headers` issues a `GET` request that fetches the whole response including the body which then gets discarded. But sometimes the receiving server or script cannot handle `HEAD` requests or does some actions differently compared to a `GET` request - you should really try it out and see what works for you.)

Comment: hiding the referrer this way seems to work and I am getting the correct HTTP status code, however I am getting the following PHP error: Warning: file_get_contents(http://403example.com/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Comment: In that case, try it with a `GET` request (just change the `HEAD` to `GET`,) maybe the servers or script you're calling cannot handle it.

Comment: Then it seems that the either the other server is blocking requests from you or just doesn't like the empty `Referer` header. Either way, it's a valid HTTP request that, in general, shouldn't cause any issues. Try putting some other URL, that you don't mind sharing with the receiving server, in the Referer header (the `'http' => 'Referer: '` line) and see how that goes.